# Invalid Character DOM Exception in IE9

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-9, domexception

The following piece of JS which used to work in IE8 is failing now in IE9.

```
document.createElement('<iframe id="yui-history-iframe" src="../../images/defaults/transparent-pixel.gif" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:1px;height:1px;visibility:hidden;"></iframe>');
```

I get the following exception : SCRIPT5022: DOM Exception: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR (5)

Is the above piece of code not according to standards. What's the fix for the issue?

Comment: Try escaping your forward slashes `\/`

Comment: This is not a standard way of creating DOM Elements.

Comment: However it is the recommended way to do it for older IEs :|

Comment: To expand on mplungjan's comment, the name attribute fails to set on elements created by createElement() in versions of IE before 8, which is why they recommend this method for older IE versions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534184(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The API for createElement specifies that the constructor wants a `string` that species the name of an element.  It would appear that IE9 is more strictly following standards.  You can accomplish the same thing you are trying to do with the following code:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.setAttribute("id", "yui-history-iframe");
iframe.setAttribute("src", "../../images/defaults/transparent-pixel.gif");
iframe.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:1px;height:1px;visibility:hidden;");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536389(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 13):

For jQuery.bgiframe.js, would be a better solution to fix the wrong IE6 test?

What about replacing this:

```
if($.browser.msie&&/6.0/.test(navigator.userAgent)
```

with something like this:

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version=="6.0")
```

Answer (score 7):

For jquery.bgiframe.js:

I downloaded version 1.1.3 pre at

https://github.com/brandonaaron/bgiframe/blob/master/jquery.bgiframe.js

and this solved the problem.

Comment: I am fairly certain he means 2.1.3-pre. worked for me by the way.

Answer (score 0):

This error can come when accidentally using standard JavaScript function names as your own function names if you don't use namespaces. For example I have a concept called "Attribute" and I wanted to try a new function that created a new one of those:

```
<button onclick="createAttribute('Pony')">Foo</button>
<button onclick="createAttribute('Magical pony')">Bar</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function createAttribute(name) { alert(name); } 
</script>
```

- Clicking "Foo" gives you nothing
- Clicking Foo gives you `INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR (5)` or `InvalidCharacterError: DOM Exception
  5`
- Opening your dev console and running `createAttribute('Django')` gives you the alert

What is happening is that the buttons are calling [`document.createAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createAttribute) and your dev console is calling the function you declared.

**Solution:** use a different function name or better yet, a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to sacrifice a little performance and can use an external library I would suggest using:

**Prototype JS**

```
var el = new Element('iframe', {
  id: "<your id here>",
  src: "<your source here>",
  style: "<your style here>"
});
```

**jQuery**

```
var el = jQuery('<iframe>', {
  id: '<your id here>',
  src: "<your source here>",
  style: "<your style here>"
})[0];
```

This takes care of all the inconsistencies between browsers and is also a lot prettier :-)

*Note: This is untested pseudocode - refer to the official documentation pages of [Prototype JS](http://api.prototypejs.org/) and [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) for more information.*

Answer (score -6):

This is a solution for jquery's **jquery.bgiframe.js**.

```
if ( $.browser.msie && /9.0/.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
                var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
                iframe.setAttribute("class", "bgiframe");
                iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
                iframe.setAttribute("style", "display:block;position:absolute;z-index:-1;filter:Alpha(Opacity=\'0\');top:expression(((parseInt(this.parentNode.currentStyle.borderTopWidth)||0)*-1)+\'px\');left:expression(((parseInt(this.parentNode.currentStyle.borderLeftWidth)||0)*-1)+\'px\');width:expression(this.parentNode.offsetWidth+\'px\');height:expression(this.parentNode.offsetHeight+\'px\');");
                this.insertBefore( iframe, this.firstChild );
            } else {
                this.insertBefore( document.createElement(html), this.firstChild );
            }
```

Comment: I downvoted this because /9.0/.test(navigator.userAgent) is evil, and the whole reason this bug is popping up in IE9 in the first place is that bgiframe contained /6.0/.test(navigator.userAgent) and many IE9 UA strings contain the substring "6.0".

Comment: you presumably don't want the bgiframe in IE9

Comment: What greim said. Do not use it, stick to standard DOM and use feature detection.