# How do I restore ViewState when using richfaces fileUpload?

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm having a problem submitting a two-forms template, where one of the `<h:form>`s is a `multipart/form-data` (ie,  used to submit files via Richfaces4's `rich:fileUpload`).

The basic template looks like this:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <rich:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{uploader.doUpload}" execute="@form" render="@form :inputForm" />
</h:form>

<h:form id="inputForm">
  <h:inputText value="#{uploader.input1}" />
  <h:commandButton action="#{uploader.save}" value="Save" />
</h:form>
```

There's also a page.xml for this template, which invokes an action:

```
<action execute="#{uploader.selectObjectsFromRequest}" on-postback="false" />
```

My problem is that `selectObjectsFromRequest` keeps getting called when I click the "Save" button.

Debugging this, `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()` returns false in this case and true enough, the form is submitted without `javax.faces.ViewState`.

I'm aware that losing the ViewState is a JSF bug and we're supposed to explicitly re-render forms to restore their state. But this is what I'm already doing.

So, is this a bug in Richfaces?

**Edited to add:** Adding the Workaround javascript snippet posted by BalusC [here](http://balusc.blogspot.de/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxRenderingOfContentWhichContainsAnotherForm) restores the ViewState and makes the form submit correctly. So maybe someone can shed light on why the explicit re-render is not enough in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that a RichFaces-component does the rerendering of the form: I made a small testpage where I observed the same with other RF 4 components (like a4j:commandButton). The "rerender the form"-workaround is only working if this is done by f:ajax.

Concerning your edit: I tried the snipped from BalusC too, but it was not working with RichFaces components again. So I tried a slightly different approach which is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408130/jsf-commandbutton-works-on-second-click). Maybe you can take a look at it.

As written there I'm not 100% sure if this is a correct solution for all cases, but at the moment this works for me.