# p:command button ajax="false" (with p:fileUpload) only working on second click in IE

Tags: javascript, file-upload, jsf-2, commandbutton

I'm using primefacas fileUpload with simple mode(not using advanced mode due to some other reasons). I use style="display:none" to make the fileUpload "hidden", then add in a inputText with a commandbutton to represent the fileUpload(because by this way I can do the design easier).

 I use javascript to call the p:fileUpload when user click on p:commandbutton(Browse)
and update the chosen file path to the inputText.

When I submit the form, it working nice in firefox and chrome, but need press two times only work in IE. Anyone know how to solve it?

xhtml page

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formUpload">
  <p:messages globalOnly="true" />
  <div style="display:none">
    <p:fileUpload value="#{testingBean.file}" mode="simple" id="file"/>
  </div>
  <p:inputText id="txtFile" />
  <p:commandButton type="button" value="Browse" onclick="browseAndUpdate()" />

  <p:remoteCommand name="browseAndUpdate" update="@form" onstart="document.getElementById('formUpload:file').click()" />

  <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false" action="#{testingBean.upload}"/>
</h:form>

<script>
  $("input[name='formUpload:file']").change(function() {
    $("input[name='formUpload：txtFile']").val($(this).val());
  });
</script>
```

backing bean

```
private UploadedFile file;
public UploadedFile getFile() {  
    return file;  
}  
public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {  
    this.file = file;  
}

public void upload() {
  UploadedFile f = this.getFile();
  if (null == f) {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("null", " null"));
  } else {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Succesful", f.getFileName() + " uploaded."));
  }
}
```

Edit:
 
I refer to BalusC's post [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183) and believe that my issue is his point 7.

After browser a file, I try to update the form with p:remoteCommand, the form is update and the upload button able to submit by the first click, but the chosen file was gone become null.

I have no idea how to update the fileUpload viewState..anyone can help?

Besides this, I refer another BalusC's answer [h:commandButton/h:commandLink does not work on first click, works only on second click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408130/jsf-commandbutton-works-on-second-click), but I do not know need to put those javascript to where, @BalusC can you guid me a bit? thanks a lot..