# jsf commandLink doesn't invoke backing bean method in first click

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i have a button in my form with following code :

```
<p:commandButton value="#{msgs['message.report.button.search.show']}"
     icon="ui-icon-image" id="searchBtn"
     process="@this"
     actionListener="#{sixteenFormController.search()}"
     update=":assetListForm">
</p:commandButton>
```

when i click on the button first time it dosen't call backing bean method. but in the next time it work correct. i check request header in each time. request header for first click was :

```
assetListForm_SUBMIT=1
javax.faces.partial.ajax=true
javax.faces.partial.execute=searchBtn
javax.faces.partial.render=assetListForm
javax.faces.source=searchBtn
searchBtn=searchBtn
```

and for second click :

```
assetListForm_SUBMIT=1
javax.faces.ViewState=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
javax.faces.partial.ajax=true
javax.faces.partial.execute=searchBtn
javax.faces.partial.render=assetListForm
javax.faces.source=searchBtn
searchBtn=searchBtn
```

do you know reason of this behaviour?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It can be related with the issue https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-790. Look how fix this issuse, for example, in the link:  [how to fixe twice needed click inside JSF page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16438847/how-to-fixe-twice-needed-click-inside-jsf-page)

Comment: i use primefaces. this issue is for mojarra

Comment: It does not metter. This is specification and issues for all realization JSF. You can look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814888/have-to-press-command-button-twice, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16438847/how-to-fixe-twice-needed-click-inside-jsf-page , where problem with p:commandButton - primefaces component.