# RichFaces a4j:commandButton. first click does not work the action, it works in the secon click

Tags: jsf, button, richfaces, render, ajax4jsf

I have a problem that a I couldn't solve. When I click first time on a a4j:commandButton there is not action. The second and following time it works perfectly. I have read about this problem however I have not clear the solucion.

I am new, and I have find this solucion: ([h:commandButton/h:commandLink does not work on first click, works only on second click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408130/jsf-commandbutton-works-on-second-click)) however I do not know where should I introduce the script code.
I have found this: however I think is an old jsf version:
(https://community.jboss.org/thread/165031)
And I have tried to repare it with: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ProgrammaticControlOfPartialProcessingInRichFaces4. However, I have not been success

If someone could explain me the @BalusC solution step by step, it could be really hepful

Thanks very much:

My code is:  (everything in the same file)

```
<ui:define name="table">    
    <h:form id= "formListCompanies">
        <a4j:outputPanel id="tablePaneRegion">
        <rich:extendedDataTable ....

<rich:column sortable="false" width="100%">
...

<a4j:commandLink id="editCmd" styleClass="no-decor" render="editGrid, editPane"  
execute="@this" oncomplete="#{rich:component('editPane')}.show()">
<a4j:param value="#{it.index}" assignTo="#{myBean.currentIndex}" />
<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{myBean.selected}" value="#{mypojo}" />
</a4j:commandLink>
....</rich:column>
```

....

```
<rich:popupPanel id="editPane" header="#{...}"  domElementAttachment="body"    
moveable="true" modal="true" resizeable="false" autosized="true"
onshow="focus(#{rich:component('name')});">
     ....
     <!-- h:Inputtext ..-->

<h:panelGrid columns="2">                              
<a4j:commandButton value="#{'save'}" action="#{myBean.edit}" 
     render="dataTable" execute="editPaneRegion" />
<a4j:commandButton value="#{...}" 
    onclick="#{rich:component('editPane')}.hide(); return false;" />
</h:panelGrid>  

</h:form>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
</rich:popupPanel>
```

What I have already tried  is to take out the h:form id= formListCompanies, and put there a h:panelgrid and a h:panelgroup

Is the problem related to the doble clicking issue? Am i in the right way?

Answer (score 0):

rerender panel and form (form state lost error in jsf spec)...  render="richPanelMantenimientoTipoVisualAjaxWebPart,frmMantenimientoTipoVisual"