# Primefaces Ajax updated form does not trigger commandButton action

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a problem with a form not triggering its commandButton action method.
When I submit the form without prior update (not selecting any node in the tree), the method triggers just fine.

As soon as the form is Ajax-updated, the commandButton won't call its action anymore.

Here is the JSF code:

```
<p:layoutUnit position="center">
    <p:tree orientation="horizontal" value="#{flightTypeController.tree}" var="node"
        selectionMode="single" selection="#{flightTypeController.selectedNode}">
        <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{flightTypeController.onNodeSelect}" update=":typesTree"/>

        <p:treeNode>
            <h:outputText value="#{node.name}"/>
        </p:treeNode>
    </p:tree>

    <h:form id="typesTree">
        <p:inputText disabled="true" id="outputParent" value="#{flightTypeController.selectedOne.name}"/>
        <p:inputText id="outputName" value="#{flightTypeController.current.name}"/>


        <p:commandButton ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-disk" value="#{bundle.general_create}" action="#{flightTypeController.create()}"/>
    </h:form>
</p:layoutUnit>
```

And the java listener:

```
public void onNodeSelect(final NodeSelectEvent event) {
    final Object res = event.getTreeNode().getData();
    if (res instanceof FlightType) {
        selectedOne = (FlightType) res;
    } else {
        selectedOne = null;
    }
}
```

I already check BalusC's [bible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2120183/2604458) and [JS Fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11412138/2604458) but without success.

I've seen similar behaviours quite often (and had to find workarounds) so I might have misunderstood something fundamental.

Oh, yes, I checked multiple times : no nested forms in my code.

Comment: Maybe `selectedOne` is `null`? Have you checked your server log for exceptions?

Comment: selectedOne is valued and valid. Server log is 100% clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JS fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11412138/2604458) which you found is hooking on `jsf.ajax.addOnEvent` which is only triggered by `<f:ajax>`, not by PrimeFaces components which use jQuery under the covers.

To cover PrimeFaces ajax requests as well, grab the current version of the [JS fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11412138/2604458) (I have recently updated that post) and add the following to apply this fix on jQuery ajax requests as well:

```js
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, options) {
    if (typeof xhr.responseXML != 'undefined') { // It's undefined when plain $.ajax(), $.get(), etc is used instead of PrimeFaces ajax.
        fixViewState(xhr.responseXML);
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tried your specific use case. But, theoretically, it should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, and fixViewState is called properly, however, the `getViewState(responseXML)` returns null (my response seems to have an `update` element).

Comment: Which PF version? The response should contain `<update id="javax.faces.ViewState">`.

Comment: PF 3.5. `<update id="javax.faces.ViewState">` is present in the response.

Comment: Sorry, that script works for me with 3.5. Even more, it's live in use at among others zeef.com. Can you please do a bit more debugging on your side? Inside `getViewState()`, what's the `updates.length`? What does `update.getAttribute("id")` return for each of them? Can you tell the browser make/version? (although that should hardly be the problem)

Comment: Yes, I'll do some more debugging on my side. The confirmation that it's probably related to a spec-bug soon to be fixed is almost good enough for me ;).