# Unable to show() via widgetVar on Primefaces 4 p:inplace

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm currently updating a webapp from Primefaces 3.5 to 4.0. I have a composite component which I used to toggle the inplace edit via a link with onclick `p:widgetVar('dlg').show()`. I've updated this to the Primefaces 4.0 way `PF('dlg').show();` but it doesn't work.

The code is something like:

```
<p:inplace id="inplaceEdit" widgetVar="ie_#{cc.attrs.pojo.id}"
           editor="true"
           styleClass="description" emptyLabel="Enter A Description" >
    <p:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.pojo.description}"
                 required="true" maxlength="140"
                 label="description" styleClass="description">
        <p:ajax process="@this" listener="#{cc.attrs.bean.update(cc.attrs.pojo)}"/>
    </p:inputText>
</p:inplace>

<h:panelGroup>
    <div class="aap-btn-group">
        <p:commandLink id="pieButton" onclick="PF('ie_#{cc.attrs.pojo.id}').show()">
            <i class="icon icon-edit"></i>
        </p:commandLink>
    </div>
</h:panelGroup>
```

This outputs a link on my page like `PF('ie_19').show()` but it does not toggle the inplace edit even when calling the function from the browser console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause of my problem. I've been using the jsf fix provided by @balusc in this post: [h:commandButton/h:commandLink does not work on first click, works only on second click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408130/jsf-commandbutton-works-on-second-click/11412138#11412138)

The script checks `if(update.getAttribute("id") == "javax.faces.ViewState")` but since I've updated to JSF 2.2 it seems that the string is not eactly "javax.faces.ViewState". Running it through Chromes debugger I saw `"j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"`.

To solve the problem I changed that part of the script to: `if(update.getAttribute("id").indexOf("javax.faces.ViewState") !== -1)` which returns true if the id attribute string contains "javax.faces.ViewState".