# h:commandButton doesn't work on first click

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2.2

I am using JSF and I have the following code:

```
<h:form id="agendaData" style="margin-left:1em" enctype="multipart/form-data" prependId="false">  
    [...]  
    <div class="form-group">
        <div style="float:left">
            <h:commandButton type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Hinzufügen" actionListener="#{eventController.createAgendaEntry}">
                <f:ajax execute="@form" render="agendaData :agendaTable"/>
            </h:commandButton>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <h:commandButton type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Aktualisieren" disabled="#{!eventController.agendaEntryUpdatePossible}" action="#{eventController.updateAgendaEntry}" style="margin-left:1em">
                <f:ajax execute="@form" render="agendaData :agendaTable"/>   
            </h:commandButton>
        </div>
    </div>
</h:form>

<h:form id="agendaTable" style="margin-left:1em">
    [...]
</h:form>
```

When I click on the commandButton with the value "Hinzufügen" the action "createAgendaEntry" won't be called. Only when I click the second time, it happens. 
I tried many solutions with panelGroups etc. But nothing worked.
Adding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408130/jsf-commandbutton-works-on-second-click) js-Code didn't work either.
Is there any solution for it?

Comment: I think, you forgot : before agendaData for the first commandButton. Can be a case, if your second button is working fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, adding a : didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Please reopen this question. The answer from the other question didn't help.

Comment: Why did the other answers not help. Please clarify first

Comment: The code didn't work for me. My problem must be another.