# h:commandButton is called with second click after navigation via h link

Tags: jsf

I use h link to navigate another page in new window.
But after click  link to navigate another page, h :command button not invoked.I have to click second times to invoke command button action.

Here my xhtml file :

...

```
<rich:column>
<h:link outcome="/demo/myUrl?faces-redirect=true" value="myValue" target="_blank" >
<f:param name="fn" value="myValue" /> 
</h:link>
</rich:column>
```

...

```
<h:commandButton value="x"  action="#{myBean.myAction}">
<a4j:param value="parameter1"  assignTo="#{myBean.myParameter}" />
<a4j:ajax execute="myTable" 
oncomplete="doComplete()" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: Sounds like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408130/hcommandbutton-hcommandlink-does-not-work-on-first-click-works-only-on-second - except it shouldn't happen after a faces-redirect navigation. Maybe there is an AJAX request happening here, e.g. at the opening of another page? Btw, it's not clear, if the commandButton is on the source page or the target page.

Comment: Thank you Vsevolod for your answer. I already checked link " stackoverflow.com/questions/11408130/",but ı could not find solution :S  Then I decided to use this workaround solution : I put invisible command link.And ı call this commandlink's action  in  onclick method of hcommand button.