# Javascript error in IE9 :- SCRIPT5022: DOM Exception: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR (5)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

m getting error in the below line of code:

```
var input2 = document.createElement('<input name=\'password\' type=\'password\' id=\'password\' onblur=\'checkCopy(this)\' onkeyup=\'return handleEnterSubmission(this.form,event)\'  maxlength=\'16\' autocomplete=\'off\' onfocusin=\'checkValue(this.value, this.id);setMarginInIE();\' />');
```

It works fine in IE8 but giving problem in IE9. Please tell me what's wrong with this piece of code?

Comment: I am getting error in this piece of code :-

var input2 = document.createElement('<input name=\'password\' type=\'password\' id=\'password\' onblur=\'checkCopy(this)\' onkeyup=\'return handleEnterSubmission(this.form,event)\'  maxlength=\'16\' autocomplete=\'off\' onfocusin=\'checkValue(this.value, this.id);setMarginInIE();\' />');

Please tell me what is wrong with this piece of code.

Comment: Same question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344029/invalid-character-dom-exception-in-ie9

Answer (score 2):

The main thing that's wrong with your code is that you apparently never read the documentation of `document.createElement()` (for example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement)).

It says (emphasis mine):

> ```
> var element = document.createElement(tagName);
> ```
>
> - `element` is the created element object.
> - `tagName` is a string **that specifies the type of element to be created**. The nodeName of the created element is initialized with the
>     value of tagName.

You cannot pass full HTML strings to `createElement`. You can pass a tag name:

```
var input2 = document.createElement('INPUT');
```

To create a full block of HTML, use this:

```
function createElementFromHTML(html) {
  var temp = document.createElement('DIV');
  temp.innerHTML = html;
  return temp.childNodes[0];
}
```