# SlickUpload does not work with IE10

Tags: web-applications, internet-explorer-10, slickupload

I am using Krystalware.SlickUpload version 5.5.11.16112 with IE 10. But because of some reasons, it's not working. When a document is browsed, it does not go further to show the progress bar. I'm sure this issue is specific to IE10 as it's working in other browsers and even in IE9.

Can someone provide a solution/comments please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a couple of days on R & D, I found out the solution using the following two steps:

1. Use slickupload.js file which is available at the following location. It'll add DIVs in your code which are required to run it properly.

http://slickupload.com/download

2. It's related with iframes. While creating an iframe it was concatenating it's name as well, which is not accepted by IE10. See the solution in the following post:

[Invalid Character DOM Exception in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344029/invalid-character-dom-exception-in-ie9)

Answer (score 1):

We use SlickUpload 5.x and the solution outlined in [this forum post](http://slickupload.com/forums/yaf_postst1648_SlickUpload-does-not-work-with-IE10.aspx) fixed the issue for us.

In short, just include this code on any page that makes use of SlickUpload and you're good to go:

```
document.createElementOrg = document.createElement;
document.createElement = function(e) {
    // iframe compability
    var icf = false;
    if (/msie\s(\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        var v = 0;
        try {
            v = parseInt(RegExp.$1)
        } catch (ex) {}
        icf = v <= 8;
    }
    if ((!icf) && (e.indexof("<iframe name") == 0)) {
        var result = document.createElement("iframe");
        result.name = result.id = RegExp.$1;
        return result;
    }
    return document.createElementOrg(e);
};
```

To answer your other question - yes, this component is (sadly) [no longer supported](http://slickupload.com/forums/yaf_postst1600_MUST-READ-If-youre-thinking-about-purchasing-SlickUpload.aspx)