# JavaScript InvalidCharacterError when scripting out a text box

Tags: javascript

Working on some pretty old code and really stuck on an odd bug.  I have a routine that is writing out some controls and I'm getting an InvalidCharacterError thrown from IE.

Here's the code:

```
var newFileTextControl = "<input type='Text' name='Q" + answer + "P" + partValueCount + "' value='' style='width:80px' id='Q" + answer + "P" + partValueCount + "' />";
```

and here is what's being written to the browser:

```
<input type='Text' name='Q22791P1' value='' style='width:80px' id='Q22791P1' />
```

Here is where I get the error:

```
var newFileTextDiv = document.createElement(newFileTextControl);
```

The error doesn't specify what character is causing the problem, hoping someone can see what I can't here.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no 'InvalidCharacter' in the HTML you show. Are you sure the error comes from *that* line?

Comment: Sorry, good catch, added the line that errors:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an element that way is kind of an 'old IE trick'...
It appears that IE9 is more strictly following standards.

To be more 'standards-compliant' I would do:

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute("type", "text");
...
```

See also this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344029/invalid-character-dom-exception-in-ie9)...

Hope it helps...

Comment: Yup, that did it.  This is some pretty old code, thanks much for the info!